# Parse plain text file with nested structure

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to parse a plain text file to an `ArrayList` of `Objects`. The problem is that it has some kind of nested structure. The data looks like this:

```
S   183166621   75783-29-8          0   -1  0   0   0   0
SS  183166621   0   DE  Siloxane und Silikone, di-Me, polymers mit bor oxid (B2O3)
SS  183166621   0   EN  Siloxanes and Silicones, di-Me, polymers with boron oxide (B2O3)
S   183166624   3087-36-3       221-410-8   0   -1  0   0   0   0
SS  183166624   0   DE  Titan(4+)ethanolat
SS  183166624   0   EN  Ethanol, titanium(4+) salt
```

So there is on row starting with an "S" which stands for a certain substance. Every "S" row is followed by multiple "SS" rows containing synonyms for the corresponding substance in different languages. The amount of synonyms isn't fixed. Some have only 2, some have 3, 4 or more.

My idea is to create a `Substance Object` which contains a List with all possible Synonyms.

I created a `BufferedReader` and try to parse the file line by line

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("S\t")) {

        Substance substance = new Substance();
        String[] columns = line.split("\t");

        // Parse columns and store them in substance Object

    }
}
```

To read the Synonyms I wanted to start a second inner loop parsing all rows starting with "SS". When reaching another "S"-row the inner loop stops.

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("S\t")) {

        Substance substance = new Substance();
        String[] columns = line.split("\t");

        // Parse columns and store them in substance Object

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("SS\t")) {
                Synonym synonym = new Synonym();

                // Parse columns and store them in synonym Object

                // Add synonym to List of Synonyms of Substance 
                substance.addSynonym(synonym);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is, that after leaving the inner loop the outer loop performs another `readline()` so the actual "S"-row gets lost.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem as you have recognized is that you read two times from the reader. I would read only once and split right away, check whether the first token is `S` for the main substance or `SS` for synonym of a previously read main substance. For that you need to have the `Substance substance;` variable outside of the loop.

```
String line;
Substance actualSubstance = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] columns = line.split("\t");
    if (columns[0].equals("S")) {
        actualSubstance = new Substance();
        // parse main substance
    } else if (columns[0].equals("SS")) {
        if(actualSubstance != null) {
            Synonym synonym = new Synonym(); 
            // parse synonim substance and add to actual main substance
            actualSubstance.addSynonym(synonym);
        } else {
            // bad format of the input file -> handle accordingly 
        }
    } else {
        // junk
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the common ways of solving this is to keep a reference variable referencing the last Substance object that you have created. You define the variable outside the loop.

Then you start parsing the lines.

If the line begins with a single `S`, you check whether the previous value of `substance` is not `null`. If so, you add it to your list of substances. Then you create a new `Substance` and assign it to `substance`.

In this way, you start a new `Substance` every time you hit an `S` line, and you put it in the list as soon as you see a new `S` line.

In the same loop, if the line begins with `SS`, you parse the synonym, and use `substance.addSynonym`. You know at this stage that you have already created the `Substance` object and it is waiting in `substance`. It is recommended, if you are not sure your file will always start with an `S`, to check for `null`.

Finally, after the loop is finished, you have a `Substance` object in `substance` which has not been committed to the list because there was no new `S` line. You should simply add it to the list.

```
ArrayList<Substance> list = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
Substance substance = null ;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    if (line.startsWith("S\t")) {

        if ( substance != null ) {
           list.add( substance );
        }

        substance = new Substance();
        String[] columns = line.split("\t");

        // Parse columns and store them in substance Object

    else if (line.startsWith("SS\t")) {
        Synonym synonym = new Synonym();

        // Parse columns and store them in synonym Object

        // Add synonym to List of Synonyms of Substance 
        if ( substance != null ) {
            substance.addSynonym(synonym);
        }
    }
}
list.add( substance );
```